# Issue in vector

Tags: c++

```
class item {
    int i;
};
vector<item> ls(3);   // line 1
item         i1(1);   // line 2

ls.push_back(i1);     // line 3
```

- line 1:

  - default ctr called once
  - copy ctr gets called 3 times
- line 3:

  - copy ctr gets called 4 times

My question is in line-3, what initial 3 copy ctr are doing?

Comment: Thank you for editing. It is looking much better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> vector ls(3);

**Your Expectation:**
You probably expected the default constructor for `item` to be called `3` times, Instead of the default constructor is being called once and the copy constructor `3` times.

**What Actually happens:**
It is creating a class `item` object and then copying it to each element of the vector. There are `3` elements and hence the `3` copy constructor calls.

**Rationale:**
One can not make any assumption how the elements are constructed by `std::vector`. The standard <strike>says only that there must be a default constructor and</strike> does not force the `std::vector` implementation to do anything else in specific in this regard.

---

> ls.push_back(i1);

**What Actually happens:**
The vector was initially created for `3` elements so when you push a `4th` element, the first first `3` elements have to be copied to new locations,so that the vector can accomodate the new element and yet have contigious allocation, this accounts for `3` copy constructor calls. The method `push_back` creates a copy of the elelemnt being added and then adds it to the vector, so that results in the `4th` copy constructor call, In all this results in `4` copy constructor calls.

Comment: His question is about `push_back`, I think he is referring to the grow of vector's internal array.

Comment: -1 for `The standard says only that there must be a default constructor`. The Standard doesn't say it anywhere. If it says, then quote, I'll remove the downvote and award it with an upvote.

Comment: @Nawaz: Completely irrelevant to the OP's Q but I corrected the wrong quote in my answer anyways.

Comment: +1. Now it looks better, though the wordings in *Rationale* section can be improved.

Answer (score 3):

A `vector` is an array that automatically grows. When the current capacity of the internal array is exceeded, a bigger new array is created and the elements get copyed to the new array.

Assuming `vector` capacity actually reserved only enough space to store 3 elements, when you push a fourth one those first 3 elements have to be copied to the new array.